# How to make rsync's complete progress percentage more reliable?

Tags: rsync

I'm running rsync to sync 2 local folders, using `--info=progress2` (show complete progress).

The percentage value presented started rising fast to 97%, then dropped and "waved" between 40+% to 90+% and now is at 99% when it should be around 30% (according to `dh`).

Why are these values so wrong and how can I improve their reliability?

Comment: IIRC rsync doesn't lookup *all* the files before it starts. It progressively adds more files to the queue as the transfer gets closer to completion. The percentage you're seeing is relative what it has looked up so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you can count the number of files beforehand (42 in the example below), and you are happy for the % to relate to the number of files, not the amount of data, you could use something like this:

```
rsync -vrltD --stats --human-readable /path1/from /path2/to | pv -lep -s 42 >/dev/null
```

([Kudos](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-progress-during-file-transfer/))

Comment: pv also accepts size.
Will probably use that. Thanks.